# conversion of string into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

in my user.data.crop_position value is "[ 100, 100, 200, 200 ]";

```
            var crop_position=user.data.crop_position.slice(1,user.data.crop_position.length-2);
        $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
            setSelect: crop_position,
            onChange: showPreview,
            onSelect: showPreview,
            aspectRatio: 1
        });
```

doing this my jcrop is not select at set postion what can i do 
it is due to the string i am passing in  how can i remove this ,

i know this is silly question but i got these kind of problem many time also please suggest me that in future these kind of problem dont came.

regards

rahul

Comment: what's the value of user.data.crop_position when user.data.crop_position != '' in the above and why are you slicing it? Haven't you stored the array as you need it? Why slice?

Comment: user.data.crop_position value is "[ 100, 100, 200, 200 ]"

Comment: i am doing slicing for removing " double quotes a i am thinking due to double quotes it is cretaing problem

Comment: where are you setting the `crop_position` value, is it something you can change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jcrop Manual](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html) says that `setSelect` takes an array, not a string.

```
[100, 100, 200, 200] // rather than
'[100, 100, 200, 200]'
```

If you can't change the input format, at least you can parse it using [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) before passing it to Jcrop:

```
var crop_position = $.parseJSON(user.data.crop_position);
```

**Edit:** If necessary (double quotes are actually present in the string value), you can use `$.parseJSON` twice, first to decode the encoded string value and second to decode the array within the encoded string:

```
    var crop_position = $.parseJSON($.parseJSON(user.data.crop_position));
```

Or just strip off the surrounding double quotes before `$.parseJSON`:

```
    var crop_position = $.parseJSON(user.data.crop_position.slice(1, -1));
```

Comment: @galambalazs: Added some information to my answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

> **setSelect** - array [ x, y, x2, y2 ]     Set an initial selection area

So you need an array not a string for `setSelect`. Why don't you make `user.data.crop_position` an **array** itself? If there is no way to change the representation you can do the conversion with a simple algorithm:

```
var pos  = '"[ 100, 100, 200, 200 ]"'; // user.data.crop_position
var crop_position = pos.replace(/["\[\] ]/g, '').split(',');
for (var i = crop_position.length; i--;) {
  crop_position[i] = +crop_position[i]; 
}
```

Now you've got an array of values instead of a string.